# Android screenshot limited to just one View

Tags: android, screenshot

I need to capture a camera preview layer content that it's taking the entire screen width and height without including other Views in the screenshot. Is it possible to accomplish this in Android? I came from iOS development and I was using this frequently.

My activity's XML hierarchy:

```
-> ConstraintLayout
- -> Camera Preview View
- -> ImageView(a logo of the app)
- -> Button
- -> ScrollView
- - -> ConstraintLayout
- - - -> ImageView
- - - -> ImageView
- - - -> ImageView
```

I am currently using this method but it takes the entire screen capture including the button and images from the ScrollView that are rendered over the camera preview layer.

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: if you like to take a picture you should send a intent to camera app ,using screenshot is not a good idea

Comment: I have to capture user face for about 10 seconds (1 shoot per second). When you capture a picture with a camera, the image will be stuck for about 1 second.

Comment: Use preview frames. Both camera APIs (`android.hardware.Camera`, `android.hardware.camera2.*`) support access to preview frames.

Comment: Maybe this Android library: [QuickShot](https://github.com/Muddz/QuickShot) could help